# How to access the methods on the actual run time objects of a list<? extends BaseClass>?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a code snippet like the below one

```
List<? extends BaseClass> baseClassList = getBaseClassObjList();
```

And the sub classes of BaseClass has additional public methods.

Is it possible to access those additional methods on the actual runtime objects of this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No not possible. You must cast to that sub class and then invoke the  methods of that sub class.

```
class Animal{
    //props
}   

class Cat extends Animal{
    public void sayMeow(){} 
}

class Dog extends Animal{
 public void bark(){} 
}

List<? extends Animal> baseClassList = ...;
Animal animal = baseClassList.get(0)
//if we know animal object is of type Dog then straight away we can cast it
((Dog)animal).bark();

//if we are not sure if it is of Dog type then we have to check its type and if true then cast it and call its methods
if(animal instanceOf Dog){
    ((Dog)animal).bark();
}
```

Even if you want to use reflection you must first figure out what is its instance type only then you can know if that method can be called or not.

Comment: Is it possible via reflections?

Comment: you can type cast and then invoke. Like ((Cat) animalObject).sayMeow() . But you need to be sure of animalObject type or check if animal is of type cat instance by animalObject instanceOf Cat before calling the method

Comment: Thanks prem. I did all the possible instanceOf checks and casted the object depending on the type.